# Open bash terminal application with keybinding/script and keep/hold window after application ends

Tags: bash, shell-script, keyboard-shortcuts, i3

After executing a command for a `bash` terminal application the window closes. This can happen when the terminal is opened by a automatism like a keybinding (e.g. in `i3wm`/`i3`) or invoked by a script.

E.g. Let's say I want to create a keybinding for `xprop` (terminal application which shows the `window id`). In `i3wm` (aka `i3`) this is usually done by:

```
bindsym $mod+F8 exec i3-sensible-terminal -e 'xprop'
```

However, I cannot read the output because after executing the command – and indicating/clicking on the desired window – the terminal-window closes immediately.

Comment: [this](https://faq.i3wm.org/question/4321/terminal-commands-on-startup.1.html) suggests to put a `; bash` after the command (i.e.: `bindsym $mod+F8 exec i3-sensible-terminal -e 'xprop; bash'`) – it doesen't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
bash -c '<YOUR-DESIRED-COMMAND> & read line'
```

In the case of a the *i3 keybinding* this translates to:

```
bindsym $mod+F8 exec i3-sensible-terminal -e bash -c 'xprop & read line'
```

**Also** – kinda *workaround* – also could be:

```
bindsym $mod+F8 exec i3-sensible-terminal -e bash -c 'xprop & sleep 60'
```

The terminal is kept awake – *by sleeping (o;* – for 60 seconds with the `& sleep 60` command.

Comment: alex's answer worked for me only after adding quotes:
`bindsym $mod+F8 exec i3-sensible-terminal -e "bash -c 'xprop & read line'"`

Answer (score 1):

You can just chain `bash` onto the end. This works:

`bindsym $mod+z exec --no-startup-id i3-sensible-terminal -e "bash -c 'xprop && bash'"`